# Instruments stopped working on iPhone apps

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, instruments

I had used Instruments tool (an Xcode developer tool) to analyze iOS applications before with no issues. But now when I try to run it on any iOS app (for instance CNN), it is giving me following error.

"Target failed to run: Permission to debug com.cnn.iphone was denied. The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer)."

Is there any work around? Is it not supported anymore in new version of Xcode? Few months ago, I was able to use it on all applications including CNN.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are using the Release configuration to run in Instruments (as recommended), you need to review the code signing and make sure that Release is configured to use your Developer identity (instead of Distribution, for example).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just edit a **Profile** section in **target scheme**. Switch *Build Configuration* to **Debug**.

[image: Showcase]

Comment: Debug configuration disables many compiler-level optimisations so basically you're going to profile completely different binary. It's better to just tune signing to use developer identity, and that's exactly what instruments complained about.

Comment: Thanks I had to profile an app to which I didn't have a release keys. Haven't thought about setting build configuration!

Answer (score 2):

First click your target

[image: First click your target]

Choose Edit Scheme...

[image: Choose Edit Scheme...]

Select Profile and make sure Build Configuration is what

[image: Select Profile and make sure Build Configuration is what]

Here, my Build Configuration of Profile section is AdHoc. Don't change this selection to Debug, cause in Debug mode, it won't be optimized by compiler like AdHoc or Release.

Then come to Build Settings, change the Certificate and Provisioning Profile.

From this picture

[image: From this picture]

To this picture

[image: To this picture]

It's done!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Exchange. In future, please upload your images to Stack Exchange's imgur. Also you need to use the raw image URL, from Github, i.e. `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yanqizhao/picture/main/img/20210119111026.JPG`. Please review my edit to see how to correctly add images.

Comment: So I have to change signing build settings every time I need to profile? And then not to forget to change them back. Feels like there must be a more straightforward way of achieving the same, and without creating a dedicated scheme / configuration for Profiling.

Answer (score 1):

The application (one wants to run Instruments libraries on) has to be in running state and then select from the 'Running Applications' category and not from the 'Installed Apps' category and that should work.

Comment: After a day of searching, restarting, updating, rebooting, and ... This one solved my issue. FYI I'm using expo custom dev client